# Oracle DB Table - To implement History,Audit and Versioning

Tags: database, oracle, versioning, history, audit

I have three history  tables as shown below for the corresponding main table and one audit table . The table are related with each other with primary key id in table.

```
com
-----
id  - primary key
description
history_id

db_comm
--------
id - refers  id in com 
query 
type 
flag 
history_id


comm_frm
-------
id - refers  id in com
scope
status
seq
history_id

audit
------
history_id
version_id
created_dt
replaced_dt
ended_dt
userId
ipaddr
action
status
```

I have created history table(_history) for these three tables.  For any change(insert/update/delete) in any one of  these three tables

- do i need to duplicate the rows in other table, even if there is no
  change in that table.

for example 
if the user has modified column query in comm table. then i will have following entry in these history tables.If you see here the com table is only changed ,but do we need to make a new entry in db_comm also.

```
     com_history

        id          description    history_id
         1           loaded data      1
         1           loaded           3

     db_comm_history 

         id    scope sequence       history_id
         1      G      1               2
         1      G      1               4

       audit

history_id version_id created_dt replaced_dt ended_dt  userId ipaddr  action  status
   1         1       sysdate      sysdate    sysdate     xxx 192.1   Update   INACTIVE
   2         2       SYSDATE                             XXX 192.1   iNSERT    ACTIVE 
   3         1       sysdate      sysdate    sysdate     xxx 192.1   Update   INACTIVE
   4         2       SYSDATE                             XXX 192.1   iNSERT    ACTIVE
```

- how do i maintain same version(global version) in all the history tables for a change in one of the table.

Comment: Why do you not use oracle auditing?

Comment: @steve: as i said ,I want all the feature such as audit,history info and versioning approach to rollback to prev version.does oracle provide all these , including tracking the web app user id and static IP address .

Comment: Auditing can be provided by oracle auditing, however versioning is way more complicated as you would also have to rollback all dependent data changes. I don't see how this can be performed in a performant way outside of the database kernel. I might be more useful you mention what you want to achieve and why you think you need these features.

Comment: @steve: i need these features , to rollback to previous settings and run the workflow and also which logged in user made changes with point in time architecture.